# How to save a processed .dng image to .dng

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision

So I use `rawpy.imread` to read an .dng image file and made some processes, now I want to save it as a new .dng file. is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: It looks like there is no image-writing function in RawPy. [You are expected to use `imageio.imsave`](https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/). Not sure if `imageio` supports writing DNG files.

Comment: imsave not works since it does not support .dng format